# EF query using exists throws outofmemory exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Im trying to get a list of `Shop_Orders` where their `order_num` value does not exist in a table called `WarhouseOrder`.  This table contains 500K records and there is an index on `OrderNo`.  `List<Shop_Order>` contains approx 150 items, each of which has an `order_num`.  When this code is executed, it seems very inefficient, slow and results in an outofmemory exception.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
List<Shop_Order> new_orders = (from a in osource.order 
    where !ctx.WarehouseOrders.ToList()
    .Exists(o => o.OrderNo == a.order_num) select a).ToList();
```

Comment: I imagine calling `ToList()` on `WarehouseOrders` isn't good. Are you trying to join two tables?

Comment: you might try to use `Take()` method to reduce amount of data, in addition to the previous comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WarehouseOrders.ToList()` downloads all warehouse orders into memory. You can at least avoid that if you'll use `Queryable.Any` to check condition on database side:

```
!ctx.WarehouseOrders.Any(o => o.OrderNo == a.order_num)
```

But that will do database query for each shop order. I assume that you can get required shop orders with single database query. E.g. you can do group join shop orders with warehouse orders and select only those which don't have matches. Something like:

```
from so in ctx.ShopOrders
join wo in ctx.WarehouseOrders on so.order_num equals wo.OrderNo into g
where !g.Any()
select so
```

Comment: Yes, thank you!  That makes sense now with exists vs any